# LINQ to SQL query succeeds or fails based on using foreign key versus using a built in navigation property

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have a query against a SQL server database that throws an `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.` exception.  I was trying to use `Convert.ToDecimal` on a varchar field, however I'll *eyeballed* the data as best I could and couldn't find an invalid value.

The query is filtering the table by a 'Group' by using the foreign key of `p.pgKey=#`.  However, if I use the navigation property and filter by the navigation property instead, `p.Group.gName='ABC'` the query works.

Here are the queries (note, originally, I didn't know if error was happening in `Where` translation or the `Select` processing, so that is why query looks weird, but as you can guess, when it works, it should just return a single distinct row of `true`):

```
Profiles
    .Where(p =>
       p.pgKey == 237
       && !p.pPlanProfile.Value
      && Convert.ToDecimal(p.pSearch08 ?? "0") > 0
    ).Select(p =>
       Convert.ToDecimal(p.pSearch08 ?? "0") > 0
    )
    .Distinct()
    .Dump();
```

The above query fails, while this query succeeds:

```
Profiles
    .Where(p =>
       p.Groups.gName == "ABC"
       && !p.pPlanProfile.Value
       && Convert.ToDecimal(p.pSearch08 ?? "0") > 0
    ).Select(p =>
       Convert.ToDecimal(p.pSearch08 ?? "0") > 0
    )
    .Distinct()
    .Dump();
```

Below is a full LINQPad screen dump showing:

1. Proves the `gKey` for ABC is 237.
2. Proves that the counts of simplying counting the Profile records is identical when using `pgKey` or `Group.gName`.
3. Shows the query working correctly when using the `Group.gName` processing.
4. Shows the query failing when using the `pgKey` processing.

[image: LINQPad screenshot]

Obviously I've used the `Group.gName` method to fix my problem, but I stumbled on that solution by accident.  Anyone know why LINQ to SQL would behave this way?

**Note**: I get the same behavior using the generated DataContext from LINQPad or if I run against a compiled .dbml DataContext.

Comment: It looks like c# is converting 237 to a string.  Probably something with your linq statements that gKey is being defined as a string.

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.  The only change is removing p.pgKey == 237, so pgKey must be nvarchar and at least one row contains a value that isn't a number.

Comment: @jdweng / @NeedsAnswers - `pgKey` is a nullable int.  So that is not the issue.

Comment: The issue is when p.pSearch08 equals null.  You can't convert null to decimal.  So the WHERE is failing.

Comment: @jdweng, when it is null it coalesces (??) to "0".  And why would it work when I use the `gName` property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries will be generating different TSQL and hence the query plan will be different.

I would suspect that the former query is attempting to convert some values of pSearch08 to decimal **before** it rejects them based on the other selection criteria, whereas the latter query is performing the other selection criteria first and hence is attempting to convert a smaller number of pSearch08 values to decimal and hence does not attempt to convert the invalid value.

If this is the case, then it could be dangerous to assume that the second query will always work and it would be best to fix the invalid data.

Rather than eyeballing the data you can try

```
SELECT * from Profile where ISNUMERIC(pSearch08) = 0
```

Comment: Hmm, I have a multi-tenant DB...I know pSearch08 is clean for client ABC, but it might not be for other clients (pSearch* are just propagated properties from a pXml data blob and aren't consistent across clients).  So that must be what is going on.  Weird that the query with pgKey worked for couple years, and now fails.  Will have to think on how to 'protect' from this in a performant manner.